# How to get table data from tables using xpath

Tags: xpath

What `XPATH` query could i use to get the values from the 1st and 3rd `<td>` tag for each row in a html table.

The `XPATH` query I have used use is

`/table/tr/td[1]|td[3]`.

This only returns the values in the first `<td>` tag for each row in a table.

EXAMPLE

I would expect to get the values bob,19,jane,11,cameron and 32 from the below table. But am only getting bob,jane,cameron.

```
<table>
<tr><td>Bob</td><td>Male</td><td>19</td></tr>
<tr><td>Jane</td><td>Feale</td><td>11</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cameron</td><td>Male</td><td>32</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for another solution, which may be more efficient.

Answer (score 8):

**@jakenoble's answer**:

```
/table/tr/td[1]|/table/tr/td[3]
```

**is correct**.

**An equivalent XPath expression that avoids the `|` (union) operator and may be more efficient** is:

```
/table/tr/td[position() = 1 or position() = 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 /table/tr/td[1]|/table/tr/td[3]
```

I remember doing this in the past and found it rather annoying because it is ugly and long-winded

Comment: right answer, but I don't see the ugliness. Also this is XPath 1.0, but in XPath 2.0 you could use `/table/tr/(td[1]|td[3])`

Comment: @Alejandro -- seems incorrect. Probably you meant something like the expression in my answer? :)

Comment: @Dimitre: jakenoble's answer works for me. Also my XPath 2.0 expression.